# prepareForSegue is not called after performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development. There are many duplicated questions (Sorry). But I could not solve this problem.

prepareForSegue is not called after calling performSegueWithIdentifier.

The show segue identifier is named as 'segue1'.
Ctrl-Dragged from ViewController to DetailViewController.

Am I missing something?

### ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("ViewController - buttonTapped()")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segue1", sender: self)
}

override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("ViewController - performSegueWithIdentifier(): \(identifier)")
}

override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    print("ViewController - shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier()")
    return true
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("ViewController - prepareForSegue(): \(segue.identifier!)")
}
}
```

### DetailViewController.swift:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("DetailViewController - viewDidLoad()")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Here is a [screenshot of storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Y5A.png).

### Output (after the button is tapped)

```
ViewController - buttonTapped()
ViewController - performSegueWithIdentifier(): segue1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not calling super - add the following to send the message to the parent class (which will in turn fire off the segue)

```
super.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: sender)
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Oliver, I know you answered the question almost a year ago, but if possible, could you please explain why calling super.performSegueWithIdentifier is needed? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @TonyStark I can only guess, but if you check out the binaries for UIViewController the function isn't empty so it will be delegating work out and potentially calling prepareForSegue before it commits and performs

Comment: @TonyStark Apple does a lot of work in the base classes for UIKit. You generally want to call super viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, etc too